# Removing Sidebars on Blog Posts for Mobile Devices Only

Tags: html, css, wordpress

My website is Onthecomeupartists.com and I am currently using the Impreza Theme 2.10 on WordPress 4.5.2. However, I'd like to make the website more mobile friendly and remove the sidebar on my blog posts on mobile only, but keep it on the original site. The posts look very squeezed to the right on mobile phones due to the sidebar.

What kind of lines should I add or remove from the HTML code?

Or is there a CSS code I need to use?

Comment: Remove your scrollbars from where? Scrollbars visualization vary according to browser, which on mobile they usually change into thin ones varyind according to OS and browser, if you run on desktop and shrink window size it isn't the same as a mobile browser, if you have a scrollbar plugin for a specific DOM element that's different. Clarify this and add your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please add below code in your `style.css`

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .l-canvas.sidebar_right .l-sidebar{display:none;}
}
```

If you want to more media query please refer this [Link](https://responsivedesign.is/develop/browser-feature-support/media-queries-for-common-device-breakpoints)

Comment: Now on mobile, how do I stretch the content to the right to fill in where the sidebar used to be?

Comment: Can you please give me your site link? so i can check that.

Comment: Onthecomeupartists.com

Comment: `@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.l-canvas.sidebar_right .l-content{width:100%}
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {.l-canvas.sidebar_right .l-sidebar {display:none;}}
```

This will hide it for mobile devices. Change the 767 to whatever you want.